# Is it possible to add a link into a flash message?

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony controller I provide an error message via FlashBag like so:

```php
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'The code you provided didn\'t match what we expected.');
```

This renders the expected output, is it possible for me to add a link? So I would be able to output a message like:

> The code you provided doesn't match what we expected, if you have continued trouble, consider looking into [common problems and how to solve them.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#sync)

I've already tried adding in it in using markdown and HTML syntax, neither of which work, [the documentation on the feature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) does not say if it is or is not possible, and there are currently no questions on SO that address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Twig will escape HTML to prevent any injection.

You have to add a filter that prevent your HTML from escape.

```
{{ flashMessage|raw }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks! I'm not sure what the most common use case is (I'm new to the tech stack) but I had to change this is `flash_messages` to work, with this being in the controller and not the template it might be worth expanding on where you should escape the message (unless it's obvious and I've missed it, in which case, sorry!)

Comment: You should only use `raw` in cases where there is no other way and where you absolutely believe the input. Using `raw` is not safe and error-prone. You should mark content as safe at the point of creation, not at the point of printing.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of manually creating a safe string in one instance and then using the `raw` filter for *all* your flash messages you can also create a [`Twig\Markup`](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/src/Markup.php) object (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508393/returning-raw-html-from-a-function-without-a-twig-filter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797832/how-to-return-and-insert-html-code-with-a-twig-function) StackOverflow answer) and put that one in the flash bag.

(The code below is an extension of Chris's answer.)

**Bad: Using `raw`, which applies to all flash messages**

```php
// PHP Controller
$newPageUrl = $this->generateUrl('core_page_id', ['id' => $page->getId()]);
$this->addFlash('success',
    sprintf('Page updated! <a href="%s">View page</a>', $newPageUrl)
);
```

```html
<!-- your Twig template -->
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="flash-notice alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ message|raw }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Better: Using `Twig\Markup`**

This approach does not generally circumvent Twig's escaping mechanism *and* it allows for cleaner separation of controller logic and template design.

There is no HTML markup being built in the PHP code:

```php
// PHP Controller

public function yourAction() {
  // ...

  $message = new Twig\Markup(
      $this->renderView('flashes/page_update.html.twig', ['page' => $page]),
      'UTF-8'
  );
  $this->addFlash('success', $message);

  // With Symfony 4.x,
  // the argument $message of method `addFlash` is type-hinted
  // as `string`. You need to get to the session directly, e.g.
  // by injecting `SessionInterface $session` into the method
  // and then call:
  // $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', $message);
}
```

You can use all Twig features you know and love for your flash messages:

```html
<!-- flashes/page_update.html.twig -->
Page updated! <a href="{{ path('core_page_id', {id:page.id}) }}">View page</a>
```

The base template retains a clean message display logic with automatic escaping still in place:

```html
<!-- your Twig template -->
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="flash-notice alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It surprises me that we can add a non-string flash message through session but not through controller. Looks like the dev team forgot to type hint `$session->getFlashBag()->add`. Should we fear that this possibility may disappear in a near future?

Comment: After some research it appears that the type hint on `AbstractController::addFlash` [has been removed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/6c4695f4ec0131a2ab91dac7ad6fb86fbda313b6#diff-af6672a1436a317ff73aea4f4bb77153b29876d8b9df1fe778425dba20bcd1c9) in Symfony 5.0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Full example from a controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/page/{id}/edit", name="core_page_edit")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Page $page
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Page $page)
{
    $pageForm = $this->createForm(PageType::class,$page);

    $pageForm->handleRequest($request);
    if($pageForm->isSubmitted() && $pageForm->isValid()){
        /** @var Page $page */
        $page = $pageForm->getData();
        $page->setAuthor($this->getUser());
        $page->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();

        $newPageUrl = $this->generateUrl('core_page_id',['id'=>$page->getId()]);
        // Create success messsage
        $this->addFlash( 'success',
            sprintf('Page updated! <a href="%s">View page</a>', $newPageUrl)
        );

    }

    return $this->render(':core/frontend/pages:edit.html.twig',[
        'pageForm'=>$pageForm->createView(),
        'pageDetails'=>$page
    ]);
}
```

Then in the twig file, something like this to process the HTML in raw.

```
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="flash-notice alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ message|raw }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```