# Returning raw HTML from a function without a Twig filter

Tags: php, twig

I have a class that has a function that returns HTML.

```
class MyParser {
    public function getHTML() {
        return '<a href="#">Hello World</a>';
    }
}
```

And then in my Twig template, I use the `raw` filter to output the literal HTML instead of having Twig escape it for me:

```
{{ myParserInstance.HTML | raw }}
```

Is there a way for a function (that's not a [Twig Filter or Function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping)) to return raw HTML and render it as such? Or how would I go about creating a Twig Filter or Function that does this seamlessly for me?

For example, I **wouldn't** want something like:

```
{{ render(myParserInstance) }}
```

Instead, I would like to just be able to use the `HTML` function call. Is this at all possible or am I stuck with a Twig function or using `| raw`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can return and Twig_Markup object object in safe way ...

```
class MyParser {
    public function getHTML() {
         $rawString = '<a href="#">Hello World</a>'
         return new \Twig_Markup( $rawString, 'UTF-8' );
    }
}
```

or

```
class MyParser {
    public function getHTML() {
         $rawString = '<a href="#">Hello World</a>'
         return new \Twig\Markup( $rawString, 'UTF-8' );
    }
}
```

Comment: it is better: `return new \Twig\Markup($rawString, 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this in support of SilvioQ's answer, which worked perfectly for me.

In my case I'm creating a filter to add a Stylesheet tag in a header block without having to worry about either hard-coding the base-url or having to pass it as a parameter to the view when it's not needed. SilvioQ's code works just fine and helps keep my view a little less cluttered.

Here's how I'm using it in my code:

```
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new TwigFilter('css', array($this, 'cssLinkFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function cssLinkFilter($cssName){
        $link = sprintf('', getBaseURL(true), $cssName);
        return new \Twig_Markup($link, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

I'm still working on this, I also need another one for Javascript.  If I change my code or figure it doesn't work I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Shortly, no, there is not.

Twig is the rendering engine so whatever you return from any of your method will be parsed by Twig and escaped unless you use the `raw` filter or you turn off the autoescape in Twig ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194115/410761)).