# Passing unescapable variable to Twig template

Tags: php, twig

I need to display unescaped variable in Twig. I am aware of template raw and unescape functions and filters, but it is a bit complicated to use them here.

Is it possible to define variable unescaped on passing params to template?

```
// e.g
$vars['rawvar'] = new RawTwigParam('<table><tr><td>HTML table</td></tr></table>');
$vars['normalvar'] = 'This & That';

$twig = new Environment($loader, ['debug' => true]);
return $twig->createTemplate($template)->render($vars);
```

Comment: No. Why is it complicated to add `| raw` to your output?

Comment: The template is edited by client. A certain variable should be always rendered raw. Of course, I could find-replace template content and add "|raw" myself :) But I'd prefer something cleaner, if possible.

Comment: You could look at Twig Markup maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44736733/231316

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning raw HTML from a function without a Twig filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508393/returning-raw-html-from-a-function-without-a-twig-filter)

Answer (score 1):

What you ask about is the [Twig Escaper Extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#escaper-extension) and from your question you have configured your Twig to have it enabled.

With it enabled, you'd need to use the `raw` filter it comes with.

Otherwise, if disabled, there is no such `raw` filter.

The `raw` filter is the shortest template directive you may make use of, but it requires you to touch the template. You can find this [outlined in existing Q&A; e.g. "How can I render plain text as HTML in a template?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184261/how-can-i-render-plain-text-as-html-in-a-template).

To prevent such edits, the [Twig Escaper Extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#escaper-extension) offers an additional mechanism. It works by wrapping the HTML string into an objet with the magic `__toString()` method and adding the class as a *"safe class"* to the Escaper. This allows you to mark a class or interface as being safe for some strategies. The protocol is `EscaperExtension::addSafeClass()`.

Examples from the Twig [Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#escaper-extension) ([License](https://twig.symfony.com/license)):

```php
// mark object of class Foo as safe for the HTML strategy
$escaper->addSafeClass('Foo', ['html']);

// mark object of interface Foo as safe for the HTML strategy
$escaper->addSafeClass('FooInterface', ['html']);

// mark object of class Foo as safe for the HTML and JS strategies
$escaper->addSafeClass('Foo', ['html', 'js']);

// mark object of class Foo as safe for all strategies
$escaper->addSafeClass('Foo', ['all']);
```

And with your example:

```php
interface RawTwigParamPureAbstract
{
    /* intentionally left blank */
}

abstract class RawTwigParam implements RawTwigParamPureAbstract 
{
    final public function __construct(public readonly string $html)
    {
        /* intentionally left blank */ 
    }

    final public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
}


$vars['rawvar'] = new class('<HTML>…') extends RawTwigParam {};
$vars['normalvar'] = 'This & That';

$twig = new Environment($loader, ['debug' => true]);
$escaper = $twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\EscaperExtension::class);
$escaper->addSafeClass(RawTwigParamPureAbstract::class, ['all']);
return $twig->createTemplate($template)->render($vars);
```

The example code is untested, so it may glitch but should suffice. If not, find comments below.

The abstract template class could also offer some method to more
easily bind to the Twig environment; more service is more service, YMMV.

---

Alternative example with a single anonymous class only, no (pure) abstract code (based on a commentary by user [DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee)):

```php
$vars['rawvar'] = new class('<HTML>…') 
{
    final public function __construct(public readonly string $html)
    {
        /* intentionally left blank */ 
    }

    final public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
};
$vars['normalvar'] = 'This & That';

$twig = new Environment($loader, ['debug' => true]);
$escaper = $twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\EscaperExtension::class);
$escaper->addSafeClass($vars['rawvar']::class, ['all']);
return $twig->createTemplate($template)->render($vars);
```

This variant (and likewise the other) is without any preference, recommendation or suggestion towards your very own design and coding style and should be exemplary only for demonstration purposes.

Furthermore widening the array $context parameter of the Twig Template's render() method (and friends) could allow a better protocol for this, but this requires discussion upstream.

Comment: Why the interface though? Seems just to be some bloat

Comment: Because you may want to implement against interfaces, not only write a blackbox implementation. I considered it better for the example material. If you consider this bloat, leave it out, move the abstract implementation into the anonymous class and register the anonymous class directly: `$escaper->addSafeClass($vars['rawvar']::class, ['all']);`, this is perhaps the more blackbox, less design is more to your liking @DarkBee. Just take what suits you from the examples. It's perhaps worth to have this as an example as not part of the existing documentation. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @DarkBee: IIRC citing from the documentation requires to give license, that is also what Stackoverflow demands for itself. Just FYI b/c of the edit.