# How to return and insert HTML code with a Twig function?

Tags: html, twig, twig-extension

I'm trying to add some images dynamically with Twig. So I defined a new Twig function called `setImgService` which basically chechs for a service name and depending on it, it will return some HTML code according to its image.

Function code:

```
$setImgService = new Twig_SimpleFunction('setImgService', function($serviceName){
    switch ($serviceName){
        case "Analitycs":
            return '<img src="assets/img/analitycs.png">';
        case "Hosting":
            return '<img src="assets/img/hosting.png">';
        case "SEO":
            return '<img src="assets/img/seo.png">';
        case "Maintenance":
            return '<img src="assets/img/maintenance.png">';
        case "Your own domain":
            return '<img src="assets/img/domain.png">';
        case "BackUp":
            return '<img src="assets/img/backup.png">';   
    }
});
// Add function to Twig
$twig->addFunction($setImgService);
```

But when I use

```
{{ setImgService('serviceName') }}
```

It returns HTML code like plain text.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Twig`  escapes output by default. To display `HTML` inside `twig` from a function you can either use the filter `raw` or return a `Twig_Markup`, which marks the output as safe so it won't be escaped.

**raw filter**

```
{{ setImgService('serviceName') | raw }}
```

**Twig_Markup**

```
$setImgService = new Twig_SimpleFunction('setImgService', function($serviceName){
    switch ($serviceName){
        case "Analitycs":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/analitycs.png">', 'UTF-8');
        case "Hosting":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/hosting.png">', 'UTF-8');
        case "SEO":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/seo.png">', 'UTF-8');
        case "Maintenance":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/maintenance.png">', 'UTF-8');
        case "Your own domain":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/domain.png">', 'UTF-8');
        case "BackUp":
            return new Twig_Markup('<img src="assets/img/backup.png">', 'UTF-8');  
    }
});
```

---

**WARNING**

When using Twig v3 you need to use `new \Twig\Markup(...)` instead of `new Twig_Markup(...)`

Comment: It seems to be safer returning a Twig_Markup. I'm gonna try it.